# What happens when you hit a nature trail with a lock?

Tags: camp-grizzly

Rules offer no guidelines to this I believe. What happens when you get "LOST" in the woods, roll the die and get whatever result, after which you roll a d10 to learn you appeared at a nature trail with a lock on the square. (Example would be nature trail 3, on normal difficulty there's a lock there.)

I think the most logical action would be to re-roll the die.